# Why java string function getChars returns string with last character -1

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee

Can you give me an explanation with some simple english words:

> getChars() And subSequence(int startindex,int endindex)

function returns substring starting from the startindex to endindex -1 .What is the reason for it. In C there is a terminating null character but it java there is no any terminating null character .Then why lastcharacter-1 in java. In this program i used subsequence function and the output should be "glech". But it is not. The output is "glec". Why?

```
class simple
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String str="gigglecheguvera";
        System.out.println(str.subSequence(3,7));
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not write the standard library, but I suspect it's so that `str.substring(0, str.length())` returns the original string.

Comment: I've removed your off-topic opening paragraph. Not only did it prevent people from seeing the actual question, but it was downvote bait. (Yes, really, trust me.)

Comment: That's how they decided it should be, don't over think about it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun . That's how it is. So there is no any logic behind this.?

Comment: @gigglee I didn't think about it, but it might be because arrays are zero based, which will make it easier to crop last index.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder . Yeah okay. I wrote it because i really got poor understanding.i dont know how to say it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun . but in subsequence function it is not starting with zero it is starting with 3rd index and the 7 is the ending index. But still it returns one character less .

Comment: Of course there's logic behind it. The question is whether you can discover the course of the discussions that were held, if they were held, to learn why they chose that over the alternative. It isn't likely; you're asking in the wrong place; and it isn't necessary. Just accept it. I find it quite useful myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startIndex` is the index where to *start*, and `endIndex` is the index where to *stop*. So let's look at that:

```
   +----------StartIndex
   |    +---- endIndex
   v    v
gigglecheguvera
```

This ends up being really useful. For instance, if you want to find the text between a space and a comma:

```
String str = source.substring(source.indexOf(' '), source.indexOf(','));
```

It also means we can use the string's length for the second argument without going out of bounds. This is handy for cases where you may or may not find your end character:

```
int endIndex = source.indexOf(',');
String str = source.substring(source.indexOf(' '), endIndex == -1 ? source.length : endIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

The null terminator in C is not the reason.

The start index is an "inclusive bound", and the end index is an "exclusive bound". This is a common convention. For example, look at [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-). It does the same thing.

People do this because it's usually more convenient. For example, this is one useful consequence: It's always true that `str.subSequence(a, b).length() == b - a`.